# How to write caller location information in a log file using Java, without hurting performance?

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j

How can I write caller location information (Java source file and line), in a log file using Java and log4j, but without hurting performance?
log4j allow you to write such information in the log file, but it uses the stack trace to get that it information, every time a log statement is issued, what causes performance degradation.
I'm looking for a performance friendly alternative, like getting the location information at compile time instead at runtime. It is possible to use annotations to accomplish that? Or maybe some other technique?

Comment: While information like source file and line are nice to have, if you're writing your logs correctly you shouldn't need them. Most logs should be unique, and will be using the class they're in as the Logger name. If you include the logger name in your logs, you should easily be able to determine the log you're looking for in the corresponding file.

Comment: @Rob, having source and line available allows you to jump directly to the location - perhaps even automatically - instead of having to look for it manually.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - A lot of the applications I work with have source/line numbers enabled, and I agree that it's convenient. But if performance is a concern, one could still debug successfully without it.

Comment: My intention is to use the location information as a unique identifier for the log message, and later compute statistics using these unique identifiers, not for assist in debugging tasks. But I agree that having location information in the log file is handy.

Comment: @Rob, if performance is that much a concern you don't log at all.  In any case, Java 6 allows that information to be picked out MUCH cheaper than before.  I don't know if Log4j has been updated to use that yet.

Comment: stack trace is still expensive. throwing and catching exceptions are dirty cheap, except the part of filling stack trace.

Comment: What is the end purpose for doing this?

Comment: What I'm getting at is, are you doing this in order to find "hotspots" or "bottlenecks", or for some other purpose? The question is tagged "performance".

Comment: @Mike, the idea is to use log messages to compute general statistics like errors, warnings and even program functionality utilization, not for tuning purposes. Besides that, in distributed environments this technique could help detect servers that are behaving differently than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making it part of the build process to replace certain placeholders, like `$filename$` and `$linenumber$` in this snippet.

```
logger.info("The original message... $filename$ $linenumber$");
```

To replace the filename, it may suffice to have keyword substitution with your revision control system.  Disclaimer: this is just from the top of my head, I never tried it myself.

Comment: Although I have not tested this approach, it seems a suitable solution for use in a production enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a more current solution if you use log4j/logback with slf4j, I wrote a **maven-plugin** addressing this issue, while not generating any performance issues either:
https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin

This plugin **injects the class name, optionally also the method name and source code line number into all SLF4J log statements at compile time** (see [configuration](https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin#configuration)).
All you need to do is to add the `callerInformation` MDC parameter to your log-pattern and add the plugin in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>io.github.philkes</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
        <goal>inject</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rob that it is generally unnecessary. Usually there's some distinct string in a log message, searching for it will get to the source. With a good IDE this is really fast.

Now, given the question as is, this is a possible solution:

```
Class Foo
    void bar()
        new Logger(){} . warn("blah");
```

for each log action at runtime, a new object is created - that's not a problem.

for each line of source containing such log statement, a new class is created. that can be too many.

here's how the magic works:

```
abstract public class Logger
    static Map<Class, String> sourceInfo = new ...
    public Logger()
        Class thisClass = this.getClass();
        String info = sourceInfo.get(thisClass);
        if(info==null)
             info = ... // init from stack trace
             sourceInfo.put(thisClass,info)
        this.info = info

     public void warn(msg)
        log(WARN, this.info,msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Log4j API counterpart to [Phil's SLF4J plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77206223/11748454), since Log4j API 2.10 there is a [`LogBuilder#withLocation`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogBuilder.html#withLocation-java.lang.StackTraceElement-) method that allows tools to inject location information into byte-code.

Recently we published [`log4j-maven-transform-plugin`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-transform/tree/main/log4j-transform-maven-plugin) that postprocesses class file and replaces classical logging calls like:

```java
public void helloLog() {
    logger.info(MarkerManager.getMarker("NET"), "Sending {} bytes of data.", 1000);
}
```

into a `LogBuilder` call with injected location:

```java
private static final StackTraceElement[] locations = {
        new StackTraceElement("org.apache.logging.log4j.HelloWorld", "HelloWorld.java", "helloLog", 1234)
};

public void helloLog() {
    logger.atInfo()
          .withLocation(locations[0])
          .withMarker(MarkerManager.getMarker("NET"))
          .log("Sending {} bytes of data.", 1000);
}
```

It is pretty straightforward to use, you just need to add:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-transform-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process-classes</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

to your Maven plugins.

Comment: Piotr didn't mention it, but he has also added support to transform other APIS, such as SLF4J, to the transformer but hasn't released it yet. Since an application cannot control all the libraries it uses we are also planning on creating an agent that does something similar to instrument those at runtime.